How to send an image in a Citrus HTTP message?
I am trying to send an image in a multipart/form-data payload in my Citrus HTTP response:
test.$(
          http().server("converterServiceServer")
                        .send()
                        //Send configured status code
                        .response(httpStatus)                    
                        .message()
                        .contentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary)
                        .type(MessageType.BINARY)
                        .body(new ClasspathResource("response.txt"))
        );

On client side the image can be extracted from the multipart request, but not be read. But if I read the response.txt file on client side manually, everything works fine.
I think the problem is, that Citrus converts every payload into a string, which corrupts my image file. How can I avoid this?
I tried the following and also to manually set the body by creating a custom Message or a MessagePayloadBuilder, but neither of them works. Citrus still want's to convert the payload into a string.
My Citrus Version is 4.2 on Java 17 and Springboot 3.2.4

You can use toBinary() message processor as shown here
test.$(
    http().server("converterServiceServer")
          .send()
          .response(httpStatus)                    
          .message()
          .contentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary)
          .type(MessageType.BINARY)
          .body(new ClasspathResource("response.txt"))
          .process(toBinary())
    );

toBinary() is part of org.citrusframework.validation.interceptor.BinaryMessageProcessor

Thanks very much for the answer. I tried your solution and also the version with a custom message from the link. Both endend up in the following response content on client side:
[45, 45, 99, 98, 52, 53, 56, 97, 51, 100, 48, 100, 57, 51, 52, 52, 53, 49, 56, 54, 48, 102, 54, 51, 98...
It looks like a byte array parsed to a string

how did you check the message content? in case you were having a look into the log output the binary content is converted to an array string, yes.

On client side I get the payload as following:
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()); and then write the input stream to a file. The client works fine with the real API, but with the Citrus HTTP Mock Server it fails. Because of that, I don't think it's a problem in the client, but in Citrus. I think Citrus does convert the message to a string even with .toBinary().
